# Linux RedHat Getting IRQs Per Sec and Record to File

Tags: bash, awk, sed, interrupt

How can I get interrupts per sec during a test and record the information to a file? Do I use itop or what would I use to collect the information?  Script in bash.

Example of what I want to do:

```
# ./itop -t -f eth0
```

Output

```
Device (IRQ)             CPU0            CPU1           IRQs/Second
                                                        TOTAL
eth0 ( 59):               0               0              20
```

I would like to report the number under IRQs/Second TOTAL no matter how many CPUs. SO pretty much I would like to strip everything except what's under "IRQs a second total" like below example.

Output for example above should be simply:

```
# 20
```

pipe out to file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like

```
$ awk '!/^Device/{print $NF}' inputFile
20
```